# Get HKCU when no logged on user

Tags: registrykey

Just to ask, if there a way to know load keys from Current User is no user active on target machine. It seems it's hard to get that information remotely, I was able to get registry information only when at least one user is logged on.

Comment: If there is no current user, then there is no current user to load the hive for. Perhaps you are looking for HKU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked not full correct question. Windows is multi-user operation system. So even some interactive user are logged there are other users logged on the computer. Typically it's [System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the same as `LocalSystem`, `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`), [LocalService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx) (the same as `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`) and [NetworkService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) (the same as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`). It could be windows services which run under special user accounts and the corresponding user are logged.

If nobody is logged and you see logon screen than `Winlogon.exe` typically displays it. It runs under `System` account. You can see as subkeys of  `HKEY_USERS` the hives of users loaded currently on the computer. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` or `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` (symbolic link to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`) corresponds `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` of `System` account. The full list of loaded hives can be seen under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist`.